# Set lc_time parameter

Tags: postgresql, solaris

I use PostgreSQL 13.2, and try change `lc_time` parameter:

```
SET lc_time = 'ru_RU';
select set_config('lc_time', 'fr_FR', true);
```

But in both cases have this error:

> [22023] ERROR: invalid value for parameter "lc_time": "ru_RU"

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name os solaris

Comment: You should be able to get a list of system locales using `locale -a`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name this command run in solaris terminal or in postgreSql ?

Answer (score 0):

Then that locale is not supported by the C library on your operating system.

Comment: I try change it to default 'en_US' and have same error

Comment: Sure, that's expected.